# MySQL update 3 columns with different where clauses

Tags: php, mysql

I have table with 6 columns - ROW1a, ROW1b, ROW2a, ROW2b, ROW3a, ROW3b.

How update ROW1a WHERE ROW1b = 1 AND ROW2a WHERE ROW2b = 2 AND ROW3a WHERE ROW3b = 3

Comment: By using three `update` instructions (one for each condition)?

Comment: Don't you mean column, not row?

Answer (score 1):

You need 3 [UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) statements :

```
UPDATE `table` SET ROW1a = 'something' WHERE ROW1b = 1

UPDATE `table` SET ROW2a = 'something' WHERE ROW2b = 1

UPDATE `table` SET ROW3a = 'something' WHERE ROW3b = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Best 3 UPDATEs.

Or use

```
UPDATE table
SET ROW1a = IF(ROW1b, ..., ROW1a),
    ROW2a = IF(ROW2b, ..., ROW2a),
    ROW3a = IF(ROW2b, ..., ROW3a)
WHERE ROW1b OR ROW2b OR ROW3b
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do an update for each condition.

```
UPDATE table_name
   SET ROW1a=value
 WHERE ROW1b=1;

UPDATE table_name
   SET ROW2a=value
 WHERE ROW2b=2;
```

(...)